# Xcode signing works but fastlane does not

Tags: ios, fastlane, code-signing-certificate

I've successfully built a cordova to ios app and signed it with a certificate. On my machine the certificate is `9********. When I try build with xcode it signs fine. When I run fastlane beta with

```
build_app(
    # scheme: "YourScheme",
    export_method: "ad-hoc",
    export_xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates"
  )
```

I get the build errors

```
[15:10:52]: Certificate X******** (iOS Distribution) can't be found on your local computer
[15:10:52]: Certificate 8******** (iOS Distribution) can't be found on your local computer
[15:10:52]: Certificate C******** (iOS Distribution) can't be found on your local computer
```

Obviously these aren't even the same certificates as the one installed on my machine. Why isn't fastlane finding the one on my machine and why is it looking for these?

Comment: Please add the complete fastlane run output to your question, so we can follow what it is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out (sort of). The trick was revoking one of the certificates in the developer console and then allowing fastlane to create a new cert on my machine.